# Dual basis for projective module

Tags: ring-theory, commutative-algebra, modules

For simplicity, we consider commutative rings $R$ with unity $1$ different from $0$ and module to be finitely generated.

If $P$ is a projective $R$-module, it is well-known that there exists a generating set $u_1,\cdots, u_r$ for $P$ over $R$ and $f_1,f_2,\cdots, f_r$ in $\mbox{Hom}_R(P,R)$ such that every $x\in P$ can be written as 
$$x=f_1(x)u_1 + f_2(x)u_2 +\cdots + f_r(x)u_r.$$

If $P$ would have been free on $\{u_1,\cdots,u_r\}$ then the expression for each $x$ would have been unique, am I right? In this case, $\{f_1,\cdots, f_r\}$ is a dual basis of $\{u_1,\cdots,u_r\}$ in the sense 
$$f_i(u_j)=\delta_{ij}.\hskip8mm(*)$$

**Q.1** Is there example of finitely generated module over $R$ such that

(1) $P$ is projective but not free.

(2) The basis $\{f_1,\cdots, f_r\}$ (or any such basis) does not satisfy $(*)$?

I would be happy if some simple example could be given from ring  of algebraic integers from a finite extension of $\mathbb{Q}$; since I have *heard* (without proof) that these rings of integers are Dedekind domains, and in these domains, all the ideals are projective.

---

Cohn in his book Basic Algebra says that for projective module, there always exists dual basis $\{f_1,\cdots, f_r\}$ which not necessarily satisfy $(*)$. I wanted to see example in this regard.

Comment: I have not made the computations but you can start from the following example: set $R=\mathbb{Z}[\omega]$n with $\omega=i\sqrt{5}$. Let $P$ be the $R$-submodule of $R^2$ generated by $(4,-1+\omega)$ and $(2+2\omega,-3)$. Finally let $Q$ be the $R$-submodule of $R^2$ generated by $(-2,1+\omega)$ and $(-3\omega,5+\omega)$. Then $P,Q$ are projective and non free, such that $R^2=P\oplus Q$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For a really easy example, let $K$ and $L$ be two nonzero rings (fields, if you like) and $R=K\times L$.  Note that as a module over itself, $R$ is the direct sum of the two ideals $I=K\times 0$ and $J=0\times L$, so these two ideals are projective modules.  They obviously are not free, though, since they have nontrivial annihilator.  Taking $M=I$, for instance, you can take $u_1=(1,0)$ and $f_1$ to be the inclusion $I\to R$ and then $u_1$ and $f_1$ satisfy $x=f_1(x)u_1$ for all $x\in I$.   However, since $f_1(u_1)=u_1\neq 1$, they do not satisfy $(*)$.  Moreover, it is impossible to satisfy $(*)$ with any other choice of generators, since every homomorphism $f:I\to R$ has image contained in $I$ (since the image must be annihilated by $(0,1)$), so it is impossible to have $f_i(u_i)=1$.

---

Let me remark more generally that *any* non-free projective module can serve as the example you are looking for (that is, your condition (1) automatically implies condition (2)).  Note that given generators $u_1,\dots,u_r$ and $f_1,\dots,f_r$ as you describe,  we have maps $U:R^r\to M$ and $F:M\to R^r$ given by the $u_i$ and $f_i$ which satisfy $U\circ F=1_M$.  If $(*)$ is satisfied as well, that means that $F\circ U=1_{R^r}$.  So if $(*)$ is satisfied, $F$ and $U$ are inverses and so $M\cong R^r$ is free (and the $f_i$ and $u_i$ are dual bases).

So if $M$ is any projective module that is not free, then $(*)$ can never be satisfied.  So, for instance, you could take $M$ to be *any* non-principal ideal in a Dedekind domain.  For an explicit example, you could have $R=\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-5}]$ and $M=(2,1+\sqrt{-5})$.

Comment: This last example is nice one (well-known non-UFD); I was thinking for it, but not justifying properly. Now I got some idea of example. Thanks for the help.